# AWS SES New Virtual Deliverability Manager - Trackinglinks are not replaced in roundrect elements

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, html-email, amazon-ses, email-templates

Today I tried the new "Virtual Deliverability Manager" feature of AWS SES. Here I immediately noticed a problem with our emails.

For Outlook, there is an extra markup element "**v:roundrect**" in our email template.
The href in this element is not replaced by the tracking link from AWS.
All other links from our template are successfully replaced.

*Snippet of our Email-Template:*

```
<div align="center">
    <!--[if mso]>

      <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="https://MYWEBSITE.com/produkt/@Model.ProductNumber" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:200px;" arcsize="10%" strokecolor="#800500" fillcolor="#da251d">
        <w:anchorlock/>
        <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;">Jetzt Bestellen!</center>
      </v:roundrect>

    <![endif]-->
    <a href="https://MYWEBSITE.com/produkt/@Model.ProductNumber" style="background-color:#da251d;border:1px solid #800500;border-radius:4px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;line-height:40px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:200px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;">Jetzt Bestellen!</a>
</div>
```

Link in other EmailClients (Correct - replaced):
[image]

Link in Outlook (Incorrect - Not replaced):
[image]

Has anyone had similar experience in this regard?

It looks like AWS SES only replaces the classic a-tag hrefs.
Unfortunately I didn't find anything in their documentation about this.

---

**My temporary workaround:**
(No fix!)
*I changed the Html of my Template. As a result, the button in Outlook no longer has the desired rounded edges. But now the tracking works.*

```
<div align="center">
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td style="padding: 12px 18px 12px 18px; border-radius:5px; background-color: #da251d;" align="center">
            <a rel="noopener" target="_blank" href="https://MYWEBSITE.com/produkt/@Model.ProductNumber" target="_blank" style="font-size: 18px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block;">Jetzt Bestellen!</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently AWS is scanning only the links that are presented in the email and converting them. There is only possibility to remove the specific links from tracking using additional `ses:no-track`

Here is an example:

`<a ses:no-track href="aws.amazon.com">Amazon Web Services</a>`

On the other hand they do not allow(YET, maybe in the future) to provide a field to specifically convert some links in the other elements (as in your case

Comment: Thanks for your input!. I'll keep an eye on the topic.
As you said, maybe something will happen here in the future.